# Conflict between my modified .sty file and babel's ngerman?

Tags: errors, packages, babel, pdfsync

There is some conflict or error I don't understand. I can skip it and nothing visible happens. The output is okay and everything seems to be fine. Still I would like to get rid of the error message. If I run the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage[applemac, grafiken]{tahbiblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\begin{document}

Testing äüöaüä.

\end{document}
```

I get the error message:

```
   ! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   ,
l.4 \usepackage
               [ngerman]{babel}
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   ,
l.4 \usepackage
               [ngerman]{babel}
```

Here is my .sty file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}\relax
\ProvidesPackage{tahbiblatex}[2012, by tah modified by sm]

\RequirePackage{ifthen}

\DeclareOption{latin1}{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{inputenc}}
\DeclareOption{applemac}{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{inputenc}}
\DeclareOption{cp850}{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{inputenc}}
\DeclareOption{utf8}{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{inputenc}}

\DeclareOption{dvi}{%
\newif\ifpdf
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
    \pdffalse
\else
    \pdfoutput=0
    \pdftrue
\fi}

\newcounter{Grafiken}\setcounter{Grafiken}{0}
\DeclareOption{grafiken}{\setcounter{Grafiken}{1}}

\newcounter{Randausgleich}\setcounter{Randausgleich}{0}
\DeclareOption{randausgleich}{\setcounter{Randausgleich}{1}}

\newcounter{Tabellen}\setcounter{Tabellen}{0}
\DeclareOption{tabellen}{\setcounter{Tabellen}{1}}

\newcounter{Sync}\setcounter{Sync}{0}
\DeclareOption{sync}{\setcounter{Sync}{1}}

\ProcessOptions

\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}
\RequirePackage{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{url}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
%\RequirePackage[german]{varioref}
\RequirePackage{textcomp}

\newcommand{\urlangabe}[2]{%
$\langle$\url{#1}$\rangle$ -- Zugriff am #2}

\def\hierlockern {\begingroup \def\par{\endgraf\endgroup}%
  \tolerance 1414%
  \hbadness 1414%
  \emergencystretch 1.5em%
  \hfuzz 0.3pt%
  \vfuzz \hfuzz%
  \raggedbottom%
}

\newcommand{\alleslockern}{%
  \tolerance 1414%
  \hbadness 1414%
  \emergencystretch 1.5em%
  \hfuzz 0.3pt%
  \vfuzz \hfuzz%
  \raggedbottom%
}
\ifthenelse{\value{Grafiken}=1}
  {
  \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined \newcount\pdfoutput \fi
  \ifcase\pdfoutput
      \RequirePackage[dvips]{graphicx}
      \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
      \typeout{Paket tah Meldung: Die Option `grafiken' fuer DVI wurde gewaehlt.}%
\else
    \RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg,.tif,.png,.pdf}
    \typeout{Paket tah Meldung: Die Option `grafiken' fuer PDF wurde gewaehlt.}%
  \fi}
  {}

\ifthenelse{\value{Sync}=1}
  {
    \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined \newcount\pdfoutput \fi
    \ifcase\pdfoutput
    \RequirePackage{srcltx}
    \typeout{Paket tah Meldung: Die Option `sync' fuer DVI wurde gewaehlt.}%
    \else
    \RequirePackage{pdfsync}
    \typeout{Paket tah Meldung: Die Option `sync' fuer PDF wurde gewaehlt.}%
    \fi
}
  {}


\ifthenelse{\value{Randausgleich}=1}
  {\typeout{Paket tah Meldung: Die Option `randausgleich' wurde gewaehlt.}%
  \RequirePackage[activate]{pdfcprot}}
  {}

\ifthenelse{\value{Tabellen}=1}
  {\typeout{Paket tah Meldung: Die Option `tabellen' wurde gewaehlt.}%
  \RequirePackage{tabularx}
  \RequirePackage{ragged2e}
  \RequirePackage{dcolumn}
  \RequirePackage{booktabs}
  \newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}\arraybackslash}l}
  \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}\arraybackslash}X}
  \newcolumntype{d}[1]{>{\DC@{.}{,}{#1}}l<{\DC@end}}
  }
  {}



\endinput
```

I also don't really need all the features. So it would be nice to reduce it to minimal features, which are needed..

Comment: This is a lot of code. In order to help people who'll help you, please remove everything from the code that's _not_ related to your problem in order to get a true [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), that people can copy and compile to reproduce your problem. In your case, I'd recommend making a local copy of your .sty file to mess around in, and begin removing lines of code from it and compiling, and over again until the error disappears, thus figuring out what's relevant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The optional argument to `\ProvidesPackage` must be of the form

```
[yyyy/mm/dd Additional info]
```

for instance

```
\ProvidesPackage{tahbiblatex}[2012/04/10, by tah modified by sm and egreg]
```

In particular, one digit numbers of days or months *must* be prefixed by `0` and the year *must* be in four digit form. So January 2nd, 2013 has to be expressed as

```
2013/01/02
```

---

Turning to the package's contents, all which regards `\pdfoutput` is wrong: require the package `ifpdf` and use the `\ifpdf` conditional it provides. Here's an amended version; notice that allocating a counter for each option is wasting resources:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{tahbiblatex}[2012/04/10, by tah modified by sm]

\RequirePackage{ifpdf}

\DeclareOption{latin1}{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{inputenc}}
\DeclareOption{applemac}{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{inputenc}}
\DeclareOption{cp850}{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{inputenc}}
\DeclareOption{utf8}{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{inputenc}}

\DeclareOption{dvi}{\pdfoutput=\z@\pdffalse}
\DeclareOption{grafiken}{\let\tah@grafiken=T}
\DeclareOption{randausgleich}{\let\tah@randausgleich=T}
\DeclareOption{tabellen}{\let\tah@tabellen=T}
\DeclareOption{sync}{\let\tah@sync=T}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}
\RequirePackage{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{url}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{textcomp}

\newcommand{\urlangabe}[2]{%
  $\langle$\url{#1}$\rangle$ -- Zugriff am #2}

\def\hierlockern {\begingroup \def\par{\endgraf\endgroup}%
  \tolerance 1414
  \hbadness 1414
  \emergencystretch 1.5em
  \hfuzz 0.3pt
  \vfuzz \hfuzz
  \raggedbottom
}

\newcommand{\alleslockern}{%
  \tolerance 1414
  \hbadness 1414
  \emergencystretch 1.5em
  \hfuzz 0.3pt
  \vfuzz \hfuzz
  \raggedbottom
}

\ifdefined\tah@grafiken
  \typeout{Paket tah Meldung: Die Option `grafiken' fuer 
    \ifpdf PDF\else DVI\fi\space wurde gewaehlt.}
\fi

\ifdefined\tah@sync
  \ifpdf
    \RequirePackage{pdfsync}
    \typeout{Paket tah Meldung: Die Option `sync' fuer PDF wurde gewaehlt.}
  \else
    \RequirePackage{srcltx}
    \typeout{Paket tah Meldung: Die Option `sync' fuer DVI wurde gewaehlt.}%
  \fi
\fi

\ifdefined\tah@randausgleich
  \typeout{Paket tah Meldung: Die Option `randausgleich' wurde gewaehlt.}
  \RequirePackage{microtype}
\fi

\ifdefined\tah@tabellen
  \typeout{Paket tah Meldung: Die Option `tabellen' wurde gewaehlt.}
  \RequirePackage{tabularx}
  \RequirePackage{ragged2e}
  \RequirePackage{dcolumn}
  \RequirePackage{booktabs}
  \newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}\arraybackslash}l}
  \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}\arraybackslash}X}
  \newcolumntype{d}[1]{>{\DC@{.}{,}{#1}}l<{\DC@end}}
\fi

\endinput
```

I don't recommend loading the `pdfsync` package: the SyncTeX technology is way better, nowadays. Instead of `pdfcprot` the more powerful `microtype` package is preferable.

Comment: What was it exactly? I still don't understand.

Comment: @smiyazaki The `\ProvidesPackage` line was wrong: check my second line against yours. The rest is just tidying up.

Comment: I thought, that egreg was to modest, and decided to add him as modifier/contributor.

Comment: @algomachine: While ", by tah modified by sm and egreg" as `Additional info` is possible, " v2.0 by tah modified by sm and egreg" (where `v2.0` is the version info, preceded and followed by a space character) would be a more common notation and also compatible with [longfilelist](http://ctan.org/pkg/longnamefilelist)/[nicefilelist](http://ctan.org/pkg/nicefilelist).

Comment: Just to be clear about this: months and days with only one digit need to be prefixed with a 0! It's a very strict formatting restriction. -- I spent quite a while trying to debug that one...

Comment: @mhelvens I'll add it to the answer, thanks for noting.

Comment: Perfect--I had to add the leading "0" to my month!